# How to get everything between <span> & </span> including tags and text

Tags: php

I tried using `preg_match_all` to get all the contents between a given html tag but it produces an empty result and I'm not good at php.

Is there a way to get get contents between tags? Like this -

```
<span class="st"> EVERYTHING IN HERE INCLUDING TAGS<B></B><EM></EM><DIV></DIV>&+++ TEXT </span>
```

Comment: What produces an empty request? (And that HTML is invalid so when it gets parsed you may get unexpected results).

Comment: my php code written wth preg_match_all ! yes thats the problem i dnt knw how to do that, thats y i asked here to get help !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` is not very good at HTML parsing, especially in your case which is a bit more complex.

Instead you use a HTML parser and obtain the elements you're looking for. The following is a simple example selecting the first span element. This can be more differentiated by looking for the class attribute as well for example, just to give you some pointers for the start:

```
$html = '<span class="st"> EVERYTHING IN HERE INCLUDING TAGS<B></B><EM></EM><DIV></DIV>&+++ TEXT </span>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$span = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0);
echo $doc->saveHTML($span);
```

Output:

```
<span class="st"> EVERYTHING IN HERE INCLUDING TAGS<b></b><em></em><div></div>&amp;+++ TEXT </span>
```

If you look closely, you can see that even HTML errors have been fixed on the fly with the `&+++` which was not valid HTML.

If you only need the inner HTML, you need to iterate over the children of the span element:

```
foreach($span->childNodes as $child)
{
    echo $doc->saveHTML($child);
}
```

Which give you:

```
 EVERYTHING IN HERE INCLUDING TAGS<b></b><em></em><div></div>&amp;+++ TEXT
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Try this with `preg_match`

```
$str = "<span class=\"st\"> EVERYTHING IN HERE INCLUDING TAGS<B></B><EM></EM><DIV></DIV>&+++ TEXT </span>";
preg_match("/<span class=\"st\">([.*?]+)<\/span>/i", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Just so long as there aren't any other `</span>` tags in the document… `preg_match` is very probably [the wrong tool for this job](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068)

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: it produces a result like "Array ( ) "!

Comment: @Truth i can but problem is beggining of the code is made with curl and stuff so i dnt knw how to join the grabbed page(url) contents to HTML parser !?    
$ch = curl_init($mypageurl.$page.'0');
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
    $scraped="";
    $scraped.=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close( $ch );
    $results = array();